# Non supported character set

Tags: java, oracle19c

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Non supported character set (add orai18n.jar in your classpath): AR8MSWIN1256

I added the jars orai18n.jar with all versions and ojdbc8.jar because i am using java 8 and still get this error.
we are upgrading database from 11g to 19c oracle .
I am using wildfly 26

I done this query SELECT * FROM v$nls_parameters WHERE parameter LIKE '%CHARACTERSET'
NLS_CHARACTERSET AR8MSWIN1256 0 NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET AL16UTF16 0
and i got these results

I have tried adding jar orai18n but it not working

Comment: make sure you have deleted from the classpath the old versions of the jar

Comment: It seems a bit weird that you're just "adding jars" are you using maven or gradel?

Comment: @shila i did deleted my old versions

Comment: @matt I am using maven

Comment: Please add the relevant dependencies from your pom.xml to your question.

Comment: @tgdavies I attached up here an image of my jars

Comment: if you are using maven then you should update your pom, have you ?

Comment: @ShilaMosammami
I added link up here for my pom file

Comment: have you transferred the new jar created in your local PC to the server if you are running on the server?

Comment: @ShilaMosammami I working with wildfily how to do that ?

Comment: I have not worked with wildfily, however in general they shouldn't be a big deal. follow the classpath you are using through the wildfily you should copy the jar file created in your local machine there. if you share a screenshot of the error I may be able to help better

Comment: I can't post a photo in the comment section

Comment: 2023-01-17 10:08:05,905 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 99) Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
2023-01-17 10:08:05,907 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 99) Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Non supported character set (add orai18n.jar in your classpath): AR8MSWIN1256

Comment: Please always [edit] clarifications into your question post instead of hiding them in the comments! Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them.

Comment: You shouldn't be copying jar files. You should update your pom.xml to include the correct dependencies, then use maven to update the dependencies. You should create a minimal program with pom.xml that demonstrates your problem.